# Integral: overlapping volume

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

If I wish to calculate the volume of $y=x+4$, $y=x^2+2$, rotating about $y$-axis, what will the answer be considering the overlapping area?
I
 didn't divide my integral into two with two intervals and I disregarded the overlapping area, is that right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Ignore the portion of the figure for x< 0 since it will be contained in the three dimensional figure produce by rotating only the x> 0 portion around the y-axis.

Comment: How can I mathematically prove what u said? user247327